# using Fgets to malloc

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, fgets

I was hoping to get some help with code, I need to take lines of a given poem entered from the keyboard and use dynamic memory allocation for each line. I have started what I thought was a general idea but I am getting a segmentation fault.

```
char poemEnd[100];  
char ** poemLines=NULL;
int i=0;

printf("Enter your poem line or . to exit:\n");
fgets(poemEnd,100,stdin);
while(poemEnd[0]!='.'){
poemLines[i]=malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
strcpy(poemLines[i],poemEnd);
i++;
 printf("Enter your poem line or . to exit:\n");
fgets(poemEnd,100,stdin);
}
```

Comment: You need to allocate more memory. Each line of the poem could be 100 bytes, but you only allocate 20. Best is to allocate `strlen(poemEnd) + 1`. And you haven't allocated any memory for `poemLines`. You need to allocate memory for the array of pointers (`poemLines`) before you allocate memory for the individual pointer (`poemLines[i]`).

Answer (score 0):

A few things need improvement here.

**1)** For starters, you're getting a segmentation fault because you did the memory allocation incorrectly. Since an array is really just a pointer to the first element (i.e. in `char myArray[10];`, myArray evaluates as &myArray[0]), then to create a 2-D array you have to
**first** make an array of pointers. Then, you can do what you already have done which is allocate memory for the character arrays at each index of poemLines[i].

To create the array of pointers, first do

```
char ** poemLines = malloc(INIT_CAPACITY * sizeof(*poemLines));
```

where INIT_CAPACITY is just whatever arbitrary initial capacity you use.

**2)** *First*, the way you've done the malloc is not considered the correct way to do it. The correct way is

```
poemLines[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(*poemLines[i]));
```

*Second*, you program will not work for poem lines of an arbitrary size since you make each character array be size 20. In your case, because you're using fgets() which stores the newline character in poemEnd, at maximum your line could be 18 characters. The 19th and 20th characters would be used for the newline and null terminator respectively.
To make it work for a poem line of any size, do

```
poemLines[i] = malloc((strlen(poemEnd) + 1) * sizeof(*poemLines[i]));
```

**3)** More of a side note here, but I previously mentioned that fgets stores the newline character which I'm not sure if you know (a lot of C beginners don't). If a line you entered was

```
This is line 1 of my poem
```

In your poemEnd buffer array, it would be stored as

```
"This is line 1 of my poem\n"
```

If this is what you want, then leave it be. If not, there are multiple ways of getting rid of the newline.

**4)** Last thing is, if your program needs to work for a poem with an arbitrary amount of lines, then that can make things more complicated with the dynamic array since you may have to resize. However, if not, just choose some really large initial capacity for your 2-D array like 100 so your array can hold 100 lines.